Hiding indentation background colors on Python line continuations in Visual Studio Code
Is there a way to hide the indentation background colors when using Python line continuation in Visual Studio Code? In the following image, I want to keep the two indentation backgrounds to the left of the attributes, but remove (or even just lower the opacity of) the backgrounds directly under them that are part of the line continuation.

And ideal solution would work for line continuation with brackets () or [], and explicit line continuations with backslash e.g.,
example = ("example line "
           + "continuation")
explicit_example = "example line " \
                    + "continuation"

However, a solution that doesn't handle explicit line continuation
The relevant bit of my settings.json file currently look like this
{
    "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
        "editorIndentGuide.activeBackground1": "#fc13c5",
        "editorIndentGuide.background1": "#00e5ff",
    }
}


if you raise a feature-request, please add a link here to it

You can use #rgba instead of #rgb with a lower alpha value to make the color look dimmer/transparent.

You can modify the alpha value based on your flavor.

While this does look nicer, it doesn't achieve quite what I'm looking for. I suppose I'm wanting some way to implement logic to decide when to color the indention background -- if file is .py and there is an unclosed bracket, then don't color new indentations until after the bracket is closed

@eigenVector5 I'm afraid it is no trivial solution. VSCode Indentation Rainbow feature supports up to 6 colors if your indentation line does not go beyond 6 tabs. You can set from editorIndentGuide.background1 to editorIndentGuide.background6but any code beyond 6 indentation will loop back with settings in background 1,2, etc.
